# database mapping to object

Tags: php, mysql, mapping

```
SELECT 
*
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.id=tableB.tableAref
```

how to fetch the result set of it so that it can identify tableA and tableB fields as different object in php. and also i can map the results in php object.is it possible to map objects in joined query? I know PDO can get the result as object but it does not map the underlying joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I recommend you to use a ORM like PHP.ActiveRecord

http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

It generates objects from your Database, associations and other commons tasks(based on the ActiveRecord pattern).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern